# Transferring data between two iframes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, frame

I have a page where I have two iframes. 
The first frame's src is linked to a page within my own application.
But the second frame's src is a url (i.e.) i am callin a web page within this frame.
However I need to transfer the data from the textbox of frame one to another. How can i achieve this ? Any ideas? pls help !

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The browser won't permit it for security reasons. If you really want to do this, you'll have to use a webservice as an intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control both end of the iframe and you do not want to give the same domain to both frame, you can use the html5 functionality postMessage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

This allows you to communicate within iframe with security (if coded well :-) )